# Prevent uploaded code to run outside caja

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, google-caja

I'm developing a website in ASP.NET MVC4 where I would like users to upload HTML5, CSS3, and JS generated Apps. The uploaded files are stored on my server and I'm currently using the cajoler at caja.appspot.com to secure them. One concern I have is that since the cajoler at caja.appspot.com needs to fetch the source from url it needs to be accessible by caja.appspot.com. However I would like only caja.appspot.com to be able to access this page, not anyone else. If the page could be accessed outside the cajoler this would probably mean some dangerous security hazards.

Is there any way this could be done? That will say, only making caja.appspot.com able to fetch the specified URL:s.

I have thought of giving the file a random name that should be very hard to guess by anyone outsider. However the chance still exists that someone would get this secret filename and be able to access the page. **EDIT: This was a really bad idea since the filename is visible in the source code**

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with was to put the user uploaded content on a separate domain. This way there are nothing to steal if someone would access the raw html page outside the caja environment.

I had some thoughts about how to enable the user uploaded "apps" to communicate with my site data through a REST API but this became a problem when I put the code on a separate domain. Therefore I now let the host page do all the AJAX requests on behalf of the guest app. That will say I provide an API with Caja that the guest code can call that will call my REST API and then send the result back to a callback method inside the guest code. I don't think this is the best solution but I couldn't come up with something better at the moment.